# Rotating camera angle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to instantiate multiple cameras that form a circle around an object. Now creating the cameras that form a circle is working, but I want also to rotate camera Yaw angle so that it also looks at the object from different angle at each step. Here is my trial:

```
int numberOfObjects = 50;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)      
    {
       float angle = i * Mathf.PI * 2 / numberOfObjects;
       Vector3 pos =  new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(angle), 0, Mathf.Sin(angle)) * 10;
       var cameraGameObject = new GameObject( "Main Camera" );
       var camera = cameraGameObject.AddComponent<Camera>();
        camera.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, angle,0);
       camera.transform.position = pos;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Transform.RotateAround`:

```
t.RotateAround(t.position, Vector3.up, alpha);
```

Where:

- t is the camera transform.
- alpha is the angle you want to rotate by
  (in degrees!)

Use `Mathf.Rad2Deg` to convert from radians (in your example) to degrees.

In your case it looks like:

```
alpha = angle*Mathf.Rad2Deg + 90;
```

(Not tested)

Comment: I have a problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004587/create-different-gameobjects-in-a-circular-way-from-one-game-object

Answer (score 1):

just use this function after creating and setting transform of you new camera

```
 // lookTarget is gameobject reference to where the camera will look at.
 camera.transform.LookAt(lookTarget.transform);
```

and here is a link to documentation for more informations, http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html

Edit : Solution if you don't have a target , you could create temporary one.

```
    // declaring temporary gameobject;
    GameObject tempTarget;
    // instantiate a primitive cube
    tempTarget = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
    // allowing your script make pop your circle from 0,0,0 position
    // it's meanning that your circle center is at Vector3.zero too.
    tempTarget.transform.position = new Vector3.zero;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
    {
        float angle = i * Mathf.PI * 2 / numberOfObjects;
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(angle), 0, Mathf.Sin(angle)) * 10;
        var cameraGameObject = new GameObject("Main Camera");
        var camera = cameraGameObject.AddComponent<Camera>();
        camera.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, angle, 0);
        camera.transform.position = pos;
        // add the look at function
        camera.transform.LookAt(tempTarget.transform);

    }

    Destroy(tempTarget);
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it automatically if I don't have a target ?

Comment: no sorry @ahmedragia , but you could create temporary GameObject located a the middle of your circle of 20 of radius and then make look at every camera to this object and after that destroy the previous temp gameObject, edit my post for this solution.